# Conference Call on local network connection in android

Tags: applications, calls, wifi-direct

I have implemented peer to peer call using csipsimple where I am able to call any device which is connected to local network. It works fine for me. Now i want to make a conference call where more than one user can participate. Is it possible to make a conference call in local network using csipsimple? Or is there any other way? Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a VOIP type application for this, you want a gamer voice-chat application like [Mumble](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) . It's a very similar concept but designed to be used on LANs and for end users to run their own servers without requiring any internet access.

[Mumble](http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Main_Page) in particular is very easy to install on Windows, Android.